# Google plus authentication fails

Tags: swift, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I am trying to integrate Google plus authentication in my app. Below is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GPPSignInDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
    signIn.clientID = kClientId
    signIn.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]
    signIn.delegate = self
    signIn.authenticate()
}

func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {
    println("Received error \(error) and authentication \(auth)")
}
```

In AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    return GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Problem is that, it redirect me to safari for Google plus authentication. After authentication is shows a message "Safari cannot open page because address is invalid". Also the control does not return to the app. openURL() method is not called in appDelegate.

Please help me. I had followed the Google tutorial. I don't know where am I making mistake.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Recommend you follow this tutorial.I recently did by using this link and works like charm.https://medium.com/swift-programming/google-in-swift-a0943352dfe9

Comment: My problem is solved. I created new project and did only GooglePlus sharing. In my older code I was using facebook and twitter sharing too.